# Is it possible to detect client-side timeouts from a Layer 4 load balancer?

Tags: tcp, timeout, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

What happens at the TCP level when a client times out on a request? Is the timeout possible to detect in any way from a Layer 4 load balancer or from a reverse proxy that is in the path?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens at the TCP level when a client times out on a request?

Things like "request" or "response" are concepts at the application level. At the TCP level (layer 4) it is only known that bytes sent but not the semantic behind these binds. An L4 load balancer can therefore detect if no bytes are transferred for some time, but it can not detect if this is a timeout where the client waits for the server to respond or if the server is still waiting for more data from the client before it responds or if both parties are simply idle since there is currently nothing to send and nothing is expected to be sent.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the answer. Can a reverse proxy like Envoy Proxy detect client-side timeouts?

Comment: @Arjun: Contrary to a L4 load balancer a reverse proxy which works at the application layer (like Envoy does) has the information to apply such timeouts. But if they are available depends on the implementation. See [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/faq/configuration/timeouts) for the variety of timeouts Envoy offers.

Comment: I guess the question is if EnvoyProxy can detect if a client has timed out?

Comment: @Arjun: *"I guess the question is if EnvoyProxy can detect if a client has timed out?"* - This is very different from the question you were originally asking. Please stay on topic: your original question is answered and if you have more question please ask these as separat ones. Or simply look at the variety of timeout options in Envoy which I've explicitly linked to in my last comment.

Comment: I had both parts in my original question. Anyway, thanks!